# Erro na autenticação de login

Tags: php

Estou consertando um código, e ele tem um bug estranho: Só entra quem é anunciante; quem é Publisher não faz o login, ele simplesmente atualiza a página sem nenhum resultado.

```
        $i[admin] = $_REQUEST[t] == "pub" ? 2 : 1;
```

O Número 1 é o Anunciante e o 2 é o Publisher.

```
// Set default country
if(!$f[country])
    $f[country] = "US";

$form = new formgen();

$adname = "Advertiser";
if($_REQUEST[t] == "pub")
    $adname = lib_lang("Publisher Registration");
else
    $adname = lib_lang("Advertiser Registration");
```

Não sei se é o suficiente. Se não for, me digam, que eu posto mais.

Código Completo:

```
<?


class user extends main
{
    function _default()
    {   
    }   

    // Forgot password
    function forgot()
    {
        $tpl = new XTemplate("templates/user_forgot.html"); 
        $f = $this->input->f;

        if($f[email])
        {
            $rec = $this->db->getsql("SELECT * FROM adrev_users WHERE email='$f[email]'");
            if($rec[0][email])
            {
                $tpl = new XTemplate("templates/user_forgot_email.txt");
                $tpl->assign("NAME", stripslashes($rec[0][name]));
                $tpl->assign("EMAIL", $rec[0][email]);
                $tpl->assign("PASSWORD", $rec[0][password]);
                $tpl->parse("main");
                $msg = $tpl->text("main");

                $from = "From: <".$this->default[adrevenue][email].">";
                mail($rec[0][email], "[".$this->default[adrevenue][name]."] Login Information", $msg, $from);

                $this->output->redirect(lib_lang("Please check your email address for your login information"), "index.php?section=user&action=login",2);
                exit;
            }

            $errormsg = "<li> " . lib_lang("Unable to find that email address");
        }

        $tpl->assign("EMAIL", stripslashes($f[email]));
        $tpl->assign("ERRORMSG", $errormsg);

        $tpl->parse("main");
        $this->output->title = lib_lang("Retrieve your Password");
        $this->output->content = $tpl->text("main");
        $this->output->display();
        $this->output->printpage(); 
        exit;       
    }

    // Short registration form
    function register()
    {
        global $DEFAULT;

        $f = $this->input->f;

        if($f[email] && $f[name] && $f[password] && $f[postalcode] && $f[city] && $f[state] && $f[country])
        {
            // Check email for duplication      
            $em = $this->db->getsql("SELECT id FROM adrev_users WHERE email='$f[email]'");
            if($em[0][id])
                $errormsg .= "<li> " . lib_lang("That email address was already used");
            if(!lib_checkemail($f[email]))
                $errormsg .= "<li> " . lib_lang("Invalid Email Address Entered");
            if (!$f[postalcode])
                $errormsg .= "<li> " . lib_lang("Please enter your Postal/Zip Code"); 
            if(!$f[country])
                $errormsg .= "<li> " . lib_lang("Please choose a country");

            if(!$errormsg)
            {
                $i = array();

                $i[email] = trim(strtolower($f[email]));
                $i[country] = $f[country] ? $f[country] : "US";
                $i[password] = $f[password];
                $i[name] = $f[name];
                $i[organization] = $f[organization];
                $i[country] = $f[country];
                $i[street] = $f[street];
                $i[city] = $f[city];
                $i[state] = $f[state];
                $i[postalcode] = $f[postalcode];
                $i[url] = $f[url];
                $i[admin] = $_REQUEST[t] == "pub" ? 2 : 1; 
                $i[zid] = uniqid("");
                $i['date'] = time();
                $i[ip] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];                   
                $i[status] = $this->default[adrevenue][confirm_registration] ? 0 : 1;
                $i[ref] = $f[ref];
                $this->db->insert("adrev_users", $i);

                // Send a confirmation email
                if($this->default[adrevenue][confirm_registration])
                {
                    $tpl = new XTemplate("templates/user_confirm.txt");
                    $tpl->assign("ZID", $i[zid]);
                    $tpl->parse("main");
                    $msg = $tpl->text("main");
                    mail($i[email], "[".$this->default[adrevenue][name]."] - " . lib_lang("Welcome - confirm your registration!"), $msg, "From: <".$this->default[adrevenue][email].">");
                    $this->output->redirect(lib_lang("Please check your email for confirmation instructions"), "index.php?section=user&action=login", 5);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->output->redirect(lib_lang("Saving your registration"), "index.php?section=user&action=login", 2);
                }
                exit;
            }
        }

        // Set default country
        if(!$f[country])
            $f[country] = "US";

        $form = new formgen();

        $adname = "Advertiser";
        if($_REQUEST[t] == "pub")
            $adname = lib_lang("Publisher Registration");
        else
            $adname = lib_lang("Advertiser Registration");

        $form->comment(lib_lang("Welcome! Please enter your information below."));
        if($this->default[adrevenue][confirm_registration])
            $form->comment(lib_lang("Please enter a valid email address, since you will receive account activation instructions there."));

        $form->comment("<font color=red>$errormsg</font>");
        $form->input("<b>".lib_lang("Email")."</b>", "f[email]", stripslashes($f[email]), 40, lib_lang("Your email will also be your login name"));
        $form->input("<b>".lib_lang("Password")."</b>", "f[password]", stripslashes($f[password]), 20);
        $form->input("<b>".lib_lang("Name")."</b>", "f[name]", stripslashes($f[name]), 40);
        $form->input(lib_lang("Organization"), "f[organization]", stripslashes($f[organization]), 40);
        $form->dropdown("<b>".lib_lang("Country")."</b>", "f[country]", lib_htlist_array($this->default[country], $f[country]));
        $form->input("<b>".lib_lang("Street")."</b>", "f[street]", stripslashes($f[street]), 40);
        $form->input("<b>".lib_lang("City")."</b>", "f[city]", stripslashes($f[city]), 20);
        $form->input("<b>".lib_lang("State")."</b>", "f[state]", stripslashes($f[state]), 10);
        $form->input("<b>".lib_lang("Zip/Postal Code")."</b>", "f[postalcode]", stripslashes($f[postalcode]), 10);      
        $form->input(lib_lang("Url"), "f[url]", stripslashes($f[url]), 50);
        $form->input(lib_lang("Referrer"), "f[ref]", stripslashes($f[ref]), 30);
        $form->hidden("section", "user");
        $form->hidden("action", "register");
        $form->hidden("t", $_REQUEST[t]);

        $this->output->title = $adname;
        $this->output->content = $form->generate("post", lib_lang("Register"));
        $this->output->display();
        $this->output->printpage(); 
        exit;
    }   

    // Activate a user
    function activate()
    {
        global $DEFAULT;

        $zid = $_GET[zid];

        // Find the profile
        if($zid)
        {
            $z = $this->db->getsql("SELECT id FROM adrev_users WHERE zid='$zid'");
            if($z[0][id])
            {
                $this->db->getsql("UPDATE adrev_users SET status='1' WHERE zid='$zid'");
                $this->output->redirect(lib_lang("Thank you, your account was activated"), "index.php?section=user&action=login", 2);
                exit;
            }
        }


    }   

    // Login
    function login()
    {
        $tpl = new XTemplate("templates/user_login.html");
        $f = $this->input->f;




        if($f[email] && $f[password])
        {

             if(!lib_checkemail($f[email]))
             {
              $this->output->redirect(lib_lang("Incorrect login or password"), "index.php?section=user&action=login", 2);
              exit;
             }

            $f[email] = stripslashes(strtolower($f[email]));
            $f[password] = stripslashes(strtolower($f[password]));

            $rec = $this->db->getsql("SELECT * FROM adrev_users WHERE email='$f[email]' AND password='$f[password]' AND status='1'");

            if($rec[0]['zid'])
            {       
                $_SESSION[user] = $rec[0];
                $this->output->goback();
                exit;
            }
            $errormsg = "<li> " . lib_lang("Incorrect login or password");
        }

        $tpl->assign("ERRORMSG", $errormsg);
        $tpl->assign("LOGIN", stripslashes($f[login]));

        if($_SESSION[login_msg] == 1)
        {
            $tpl->parse("main.msg");
            $_SESSION[login_msg] = 0;
        }

        $tpl->parse("main");
        $this->output->title = lib_lang("Login");
        $this->output->content = $tpl->text("main");
        $this->output->display();
        $this->output->printpage(); 
        exit;
    }   

    // Logout
    function logout()
    {
        global $f;

        $_SESSION['user'] = array();
        $this->output->redirect(lib_lang("You are now logged out"), "index.php");
        exit;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Com pedaços de código e funções que não sabemos o que significa, fica muito difícil deduzir, reformule **a pergunta** se baseando nestas dicas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Tente com um `echo` verificar a saída da variável `$i[admin]` e veja se a *string* é mesmo `pub`. Na função `login` no final da sql têm `AND status='1'` têm certeza que esse valor é o correto?

Comment: O erro está na sua lógica ,-,

Comment: Tem sítios em que utilizas `quotes` e outros em que simplesmente não utilizas tal como `$_SESSION[user]` e `if($f[email] && $f[password])`. Isso pode causar-te alguns problemas pois neste caso, php irá procurar por uma constante com o nome user, email e password, mas, será isso que pretendes?